# http post object with object list not bound

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, http-post

I already read about model binding ( http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx ) and I know how it should work, but unfortunately, the mvc binding doesnt work correct if i do the following

I'm Posting the following Data but my mvc controller doesnt bind the values correctly.

```
competenceRatings[0].comment    
competenceRatings[0].ratingSchemeId 
competenceRatings[0].ratingRevisedSchemeId  cf1235bb-e30f-4d3d-8002-259b3d6205c9_f203335d-3e49-4c2b-b943-2a0e3e053e92
competenceRatings[1].comment    
competenceRatings[1].ratingSchemeId     
competenceRatings[1].ratingRevisedSchemeId  7a7aebc0-fbb6-4677-93de-5b8a53c43615_dd35f361-6c77-4ffa-b49f-57a8958ca362
exerciseScenarioId  fba8aaa0-d141-484f-bcbe-564004b479b9
observerId  c7679e20-45de-4742-912a-0a234daf7244
participantId   c7679e20-45de-4742-912a-0a234daf7243
ratingTypeId    a457b1c5-669a-4496-9491-3906bbb83725
sheetId c7679e20-45de-4742-912a-0a234daf7232
```

My used classes:

```
public class SheetRatingViewModel
{
    public Guid sheetId { get; set; }     
    public Guid ratingTypeId { get; set; }
    public Guid participantId { get; set; }
    public Guid observerId { get; set; }
    public Guid exerciseScenarioId { get; set; }
    List<RatingViewModel> competenceRatings { get; set; }
}

public class RatingViewModel
{
    public String ratingSchemeId { get; set; }
    public String ratingRevisedSchemeId { get; set; }
    public String comment { get; set; }
}
```

My controller

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create(SheetRatingViewModel sheetRating)
 { .... }
```

Does somebody has any ideas why the posted input fields, which are named like a list, are not bound to the property "competenceRatings"? The single properties are correctly bound.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your complete view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<RatingViewModel> competenceRatings { get; set; }
```

This one has to be public like your other properties in SheetRatingViewModel. The modelbinder can only bind to public properties.